# RedBeanPHP. Restricción setMeta(...) para columnas UNIQUE no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Estoy utilizando [redbeanphp](/questions/tagged/redbeanphp) 5.1.0 con [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) y [php](/questions/tagged/php) e intentando conseguir que el valor de una columna (o atributo de un bean) sean únicos (restricción UNIQUE sobre la columna creada)

Según la propia documentación de RedBeanPHP y varios artículos de Google, bastaría con utilizar la función setMeta(...), pero no funciona.

Éste es el código que he probado.

```
<?php

include 'rb.php';
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

R::nuke();

$bean = R::dispense('bean');
$bean->name = 'any';

$bean -> setMeta('buildcommand.unique', array(array('name')) );
R::store($bean);

$another_bean = R::dispense('bean');
$another_bean->name = 'any';

R::store($another_bean); // ¡¡ funciona !!, cuando debería saltar una excepción

?>
```

También he probado, según he visto en Google con otras opciones (creo que obsoletas del setMeta(...):

```
$bean -> setMeta('buildcommand.unique.0', array('name') );
```

... y con ...

```
$bean -> setMeta('sys.uniques', array('name') );
```

...y otras del estilo. También he probado con otra base de datos (distinta a "test" y otro usuario y nada). Pensé que podría ser algún tema de privilegios que impedía hacer un ALTER TABLE.

También he activado un 
    R::debug(true)

...y no veo que redBeanPHP intente hacer ningún ALTER TABLE para añadir la restricción.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Me han contestado desde el [foro de StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49903179/9662888).

Me temo que desde la versión 4.2.0 ya no funcionan los `setMeta(...)`

Lo que no tengo claro es si hay algún otro *workaround* para que funcionen estas restricciones UNIQUE desde RedBeanPHP.